# Unskewed text that aligns along the edge of a skewed div

Tags: html, css, frontend, skew

I'm trying to produce normal text within a skewed div.  I want to maintain alignment along the edge of the skewed div like this:

[image: skewed_perspective]

That code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/WU8gT/8/

It's not pretty; each element is wrapped in a floated span.

```
<div class="section_header twist_right">
  <span class="float twist_left">The&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">Quick&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">Brown&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">Fox&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">Jumped&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">Over&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">The&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">Lazy&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="float twist_left">Dog&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

**Is there any way to achieve this functionality in one text wrapper?**  Such as:

```
<div class="section_header twist_right">
  <p class="twist_left"> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</p>
</div>
```

I have not been able to get the above to work as it still aligns the text along a vertical edge.  Curious if anyone else has come across this or knows a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am looking for a good answer for such a question that isn't a performance hog, horrifically hacky, and well supported.

The closest I could find are Adobe's efforts with CSS3 shapes.

http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/shapes/